# add class to span element with onClick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onclick, html

I'm searching hours for an solution and found some answers, but not a quite fitting one.

I have several `<span id="same-id-for-all-spans"></span>` elements with each of them including one `<img>` element.
Now I want to create a print template, to only print those  elements which have a specific **class** added to it.

The question is, how can I add a **class** to a span by clicking on it. 
This way I want to "mark" several spans which then have an underlying print-css style to only print the ones with the specific**class**.
**Important:** It should be possible to click (add class) and reclick (delete class) for single spans.

Thank you so much.
Best Regards
Mazey

---

its a wordpress return for all the spans, so same id. 
at the moment I have this js included:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeid ()
{
var e = document.getElementById("nonprintable");
e.id = "printable";
}

</script>
```

---

and the wordpress code looks like this:

```
<?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post->ID,  'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'); 
                $attachments = get_children($args); 
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {


echo '<span id="nonprintable"  onClick="changeid()" >';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );

      echo '</span>';

          }


?>
```

---

Right now when I click on a span I see that it changes the id. But it changes it just top to bottom with every click on a span and not on a specific span I click.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: any reason you have got same id for all spans?

Comment: can you not edit he PHP code where it assigns a unique ID to the span? Are you thinking of setting IDs after the page has been rendered? I dont think thats a good idea whatever it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: like explained above, I want to add classes to the spans afterwards, so that in the print template the class-name decides which image is displayed, and which ones are not. If u have any other suggestion, I'm happy :)

Comment: I think I dont need the "id". The "class" I only need for the print template. Instead of the "id" I only want to change the style of the span. So when I click one, I want it to have a border. **Can someone help me with that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
jQuery('span').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('yourSpecialClass');
});
```

Comment: This would grab all the span elements on the page which might not be desired.

Comment: Hi, thanks at first.
sadly it doesnt work :(
My setting explained above is working, except that it just changes the id in sequence, instead of just on the span I'm clicking. Thats because of the same id name I know. 
But how can I integrate the $this in my code...so that it only changes the id of the span I'm actually clicking?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not have the same id for all your spans. Instead add a class to all of them like this:

```
<span class="selectable"></span>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".selectable").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

And then in your function

```
function getAllSelected(){
   var selected = $(".selected"); // This will give you all the selected elements.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could use the following

```
$("span").click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass("classname"))
   {
      $(this).removeClass("classname");
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).addClass("classname");
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` handler and toggle CSS classes:

JS:

```
function addClass(obj) {
    obj.className ? obj.className = "" : obj.className = "test";
}
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML Span:

```
<span onclick="addClass(this)">Click me!</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yXWcW/1/

Edit: Didn't see the jQuery tag, use `toggleClass` for that.

Comment: Hi,
I have an additional question.
How is the way, if I want to add an "id" instead of a "class"?
thank u.

Comment: If you want to add an `id`, you can do `obj.id = "newId"`; remember, ID's should be unique as well.

Comment: Hi again tymeJV. Could you help with adding a style="" tag to the span on click? 
Already tried with 

function addClass(obj) {
    obj.className ? obj.className = "" : obj.className = " noprint";
 obj.css({
    border: "5px solid #E3E3E3", 
    margin: "5px", 
    display: "inline-block" 

});}
but its not working. 
Thank you.

Comment: You were close, since you also have jQuery, use `$(obj).css({ border: "5px solid #E3E3E3", margin: "5px", display: "inline-block" })`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<span id="nonprintable"  onClick="changeid(this)" >
```

added "this" to arguments

and your function would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeid (e){//added e to accepted arguments
    e.id = "printable";
    //e is the element so you are only changing that one elements id
}
</script>
```

or you can just use jQuery's .toggleClass

```
<span onclick="$(this).toggleClass('your-classname');">Click me!</span>
```

Since you have multiple instances (I would recomend classes instead of id's)

```
$('#same-id-for-all-spans').click(function(){

    $(this).toggleClass('your-classname');

});
```

Here is the jQuery doc for .toggleClass()

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="items">
        <span class="item">Click Item 1</span>    
        <span class="item">Click Item 2</span>  
        <span class="item">Click Item 3</span>  
    </div>

   <div class="btn-getSelectedItems">Get Selected Items</div>

   $(function(){
        $('.items .item').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        })

       $('.btn-getSelectedItems').click(function(){
         if($('.items .selected').length){
            console.log($('.items .selected'))
         }
       })
    })
```